# Sending email using javascript but deleting part of timestamp

Tags: javascript, email

Hi I'm sending an email using java script taking the information from a form when it is submitted on a google spreadsheet.

This is my code well a test version only small for fixing problems like this one im having.

```
function formSubmitted(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();

  var timestamp = sheet.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
  var username = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getValue();
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "test@gmail.com",
      subject: "test",
      body: "Timestamp: " + timestamp + 
            "\nUsername: " + username + 
            "\nName: " + name +

    });
};
```

Ok so this works pefectly besides the timestamp bit which give me the result say
Fri May 17 2013 09:32:02 GMT+0100 (BST)
But I want it to look like
Fri May 17 2013 09:32:02
I wanna remove the GMT bit as this is not needed in the email.

Any idea on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function like `replace()` and `split()`.

```
timestamp = timestamp.replace("GMT","-").split("-")[0];
```

This will exclude the unwanted substring.

Comment: I tried to do something like that but i keep getting a error saying
TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object Wed May 01 2013 10:24:04 GMT+0100 (BST). (line 43, file "RaysTestFile")

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hXPnX/) is working... Maybe your timestamp variable is not a string. Try to use `toString()` on it or any other way related to your spreadsheetapp to get a string value!

Comment: Thanks ya all i needed to do was change it to a string after i got the value then i tried the code again the way i was working on before hand and it worked but your was is simpler so that will be better thanks :)

Comment: I never taught of it cause i taught i already had changed it to a string :) ah well.. Ya will do thanks again

Comment: @RayRay I'm guessing it's a `Date()` object - when it was appended to the string, that automatically called its `toString()` method.